# GMail and Yahoo Mail servers not accepting mails from my slicehost slice

Tags: postfix, email

I have a rails in one of the slices at Slicehost. I've setup postfix (sendmail) to send emails from my rails app.

All emails to Google Apps domain (to company setup google hosted paid email id) are getting delivered properly (but to spam folder).

But all emails to ...@gmail.com, ...@yahoo.com, .. @hotmail.com are not getting delivered and this is the line from my /var/log/mail.log

```
Dec 21 17:33:56 staging postfix/smtp[32295]: 5EB4810545B: to=<somesecret@yahoo.com>, relay=j.mx.mail.yahoo.com[66.94.237.64]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.02/0.01/1.5/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host j.mx.mail.yahoo.com[66.94.237.64] refused to talk to me: 553 Mail from 173.203.201.186 not allowed - 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections not accepted from IP addresses on Spamhaus PBL; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/errors/550-bl21.html [550])
```

and this is what i got for gmail

```
Dec 21 17:29:17 staging postfix/smtp[32216]: 0FA3310545B: to=<somesecret@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.65.27]:25, delay=0.59, delays=0.02/0.01/0.09/0.47, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.65.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [173.203.201.186] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized 550-5.7.1 to send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at 550-5.7.1 your service provider instead. Learn more at                          550 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336 v49si11176750yhc.16 (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Please help. I have very little knowledge about setting dns, servers and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ip address (of the slice) is blacklisted at SpamHaus.

That is why emails are not being accepted. I would ask slicehost to provide you with a new ip address.

HEre is a link to check blacklists: http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a173.203.201.186

Here is an article on how to get the ip removed from spamhaus but keep in mind the chances of being able to remove it are dificult. it is easier to get a new ip from your provider.
http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/1/20/removing-a-mail-server-from-the-spamhaus-pbl

hope this helps.

Comment: what about Gmail then. Gmail error is a different one - what can i do about that... :(

Comment: it is most likely the same problem even with the slightly different error.

Comment: SliceHost may also offer a smarthost (relay) for you to use instead of sending mail directly.

Comment: thanks a lot. i've removed it. what can i do to prevent my ip from getting listed again in spam blocklists ?

Comment: Make sure you are not spamming :), keep your server up to date, patched, good root password, no root logins (login as a user first and use sudo etc, make sure your mail server does not allow email being sent without things like authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure if Slicehost uses shared IPs or dedicated IPs, but if it is the former, you do not fully control whether or not people will spam. Suggest you find a service like [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) (Mine!) or [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com) to manage your email for you - they keep IPs clean for people just like yourself!

Answer (score 1):

This article may help: [Removing a mail server from the Spamhaus PBL](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/1/20/removing-a-mail-server-from-the-spamhaus-pbl)